# Cluster a set of files by the the number of points

Tags: r, clustering, outliers

I have a large set of aerial images with herds of elephants in it. The number of elephants in a single image can range from ~ 20 elephants to 1.

I have created a dataset of ~ 2,000 png image files which lists the image_filename and the number of elephants in it (objects). Here's an example of the first few rows

```
> df <- data.frame(image = c("000000000.png", "000000001.png", "000000002.png", "000000003.png", "000000004.png", "000000005.png"),
                    objects = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 30))
```

| image | objects |
| --- | --- |
| 000000000.png | 1 |
| 000000001.png | 1 |
| 000000002.png | 1 |
| 000000003.png | 4 |
| 000000004.png | 1 |
| 000000005.png | 20 |

When I create a frequency table of this data, I can see that some herd sizes are more common than others. For example, images with 8 or 9 elephants in it occur more than images with 11 or 12 elephants. Images with 15 elephants also seem to occur more than once.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 19 | 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1456 | 295 | 110 | 53 | 24 | 14 | 15 | 7 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

I would like to make sense of this by finding out A) which herd sizes are common in images (e.g. images with 8 or 9 elephants are more common), B) which herd sizes are unique / outliers (e.g., let's say there's a single image with 20 elephants but all the others images have herd sizes of less than 10), and C) which image filenames belong in each cluster.

Instead of visually looking at these results and trying to arbitrarily group them, is there a quantitative way to cluster these common and unique herd sizes into groupings?

Comment: Because the answers are so evident from the data, you likely would not benefit from the additional work of applying any clustering procedure.

Comment: I've used a basic example dataframe to easily explain the problem. As is common in data science, I will apply this methodology to multiple datasets with tens of thousands of images, where a standardised quantitative method (e.g., clustering) will be beneficial over the visual/manual work described above.

Comment: As the problem is described, you have a 1 dimension data set (frequency of herd size) in ~20 categories.  Performing a clustering algorithm is not going to provide additional information.  If you start adding in additional dimensions such as season, time of day, type of vegetation, then clustering can provide additional insights.

Comment: @Dave2e Given I want to quantitively group a 1-dimensional dataset on the basis of herd size, what approach would you recommend? I appreciate clustering may not be the right method, so any insight into what would be the most appropriate method for my task (grouping by herd size) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The intention to automate this procedure subtly changes the question and appreciably changes the possible good answers, so please edit your post to clarify your aims.  In the meantime, check out some of our existing answers by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cluster+%221-D%22).  Refine that search, if you like, by including "Jenks" as a keyword.

Comment: @whuber
I'm not sure you've fully read the post before commenting and therefore you may have misunderstood it. The post clearly states I am looking for a quantitative solution, rather than an arbitrary visual/manual approach. If 'the answers are so evident' that they do not require 'additional work', as you claim, please do provide the 'evident answers' to questions A, B and C.

Comment: I have read your post several times, with each edit, and have nothing more to add or remove from my comments.

Comment: @whuber, comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems, please stick to using comments for that purpose rather than posting unhelpful comments.

If 'the answers are so evident' that they do not require 'additional work', as you state, please do post the answers. If not, then please clarify.

Comment: @whuber Just to make my point as clear as crystal and as easy to understand as possible: **Stating that 'the answers are so evident'** and refusing to post the answers or explain how so is unhelpful. **Showing how 'the answers are so evident'** with an answer or explanation is helpful.

Comment: I invite you to plot the data, then.

Comment: @whuber Please show how 'the answers are so evident' with a post or more informative comment. Curt comments and being unnecessarily obtuse are not in the spirit of StackExchange. Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Please provide an answer if you're capable of doing so.